# Can't debug shared library with gdb

Tags: linux, debugging, gdb, shared-libraries

When I attach to process with GDB I saw that warning:

```
Reading symbols from /CloneFileSystem/lib/ld-uClibc.so.0...
(No debugging symbols found in /CloneFileSystem/lib/ld-uClibc.so.0)
warning: Unable to find dynamic linker breakpoint function.
GDB will be unable to debug shared library initializers
and track explicitly loaded dynamic code.
```

Even I use `set sysroot /CloneFileSystem` with all the libraries there, that not help.

My process call to function in shared library and that function call to another function in another shared library.

For example ProcessFunc-> Lib1Func -> Lib2Func

I want to debug Lib2Func but when I run command
`b Lib2Func`
gdb can't set a breakpoint there event that library is already loaded

`file myexe` -> `interpreter /lib/ld-uClibc.so.0`

When I use `info sharedlibrary` in GDB I can't the value in From and To (address of loaded are empty)

Comment: Do you have the dynamic loader (ld.so or ld-linux.so or whatever) in your cloned sysroot?  Run `file ./myexe` to see the dynamic loader specified for `./myexe`.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. When I run `file` on this exe I got `interpreter /lib/ld-uClibc.so.0` and I have this file in `lib` (I update my post)

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try recompiling the library with a -g option.  It's saying it can't find the debug info. -g provides for debugging info if you are using gcc.  This is the first thing i'd check.  If the library is big this may take awhile.

Comment: I can't recompiling the library :)

Comment: I think i understand.  Then you only have only compiled binaries?  I don't think you would be able to do this with gdb without having the source.  You might have to use a traditional IDE debugger(if you just want to debug the code), even though gdb is way cooler.  I think I had a similar problem a while back when I tried to look at c stdlib functions in gdb.